# Is it possible to use Http.POST with Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am using [Universal Image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to attempt to load images using http POST instead of regular GET. The POST request will have data in the BODY (key value pair).

Is there a way to do this using Universal Image Loader?

So far I've tried extending the BaseImageDownloader for the configuration, but i think i'm missing something else:

```
public class SmartImageDownloader extends BaseImageDownloader {

/**
 * Constructor
 * @param context
 */
public SmartImageDownloader(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public InputStream getStream(String imageUri, Object extra) throws IOException {
    switch (Scheme.ofUri(imageUri)) {
        case HTTP:
        case HTTPS:
            KLog.e(TAG, "getStream: " + extra.toString(), KLog.Severity.WTF);
            HttpURLConnection conn = createConnection(imageUri, extra);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

            writer.write(getQuery((List<NameValuePair>)extra));
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();


            return new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream(), BUFFER_SIZE);
        case FILE:
            return getStreamFromFile(imageUri, extra);
        case CONTENT:
            return getStreamFromContent(imageUri, extra);
        case ASSETS:
            return getStreamFromAssets(imageUri, extra);
        case DRAWABLE:
            return getStreamFromDrawable(imageUri, extra);
        case UNKNOWN:
        default:
            return getStreamFromOtherSource(imageUri, extra);
    }
}

private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    for (NameValuePair pair : params)
    {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
}
```

I attempt to load the image in my adaptor by calling something like this:

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(IMAGEURL,
                                             IMAGEVIEW,
                                            DisplayOptionsUtil.DefaultDisplayImageOptions(ImageUtil.GenerateRequestParamsForImage(cnf, ImageSize.LARGE)));
```

Where:

```
public static final DisplayImageOptions DefaultDisplayImageOptions(List<NameValuePair> params){
    return new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .imageDownloader(new SmartImageDownloader(this))
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
            .extraForDownloader(params)
            .build();
}
```

What i;m trying to do is that for loading images for an image view, i construct a DisplayImageOptions with the post params as extras. Currently it keeps coming back saying java.io.FileNotFoundException. Anyone can give me a pointer? Thanks!

Comment: Did you set `SmartImageDownloader` in configuration?

Comment: @NOSTRA Yes i did. I had it initialized once in my application instance. I have used UIL for purely HTTP.GET on images, this time i just want to get it through a POST request.

Comment: It seems you're doing everything right but I can't say why you got `FileNotFoundException`. My be your URL is wrong, or params. Maybe try to debug.

Comment: @NOSTRA Yea i did some test and it seems like the part on HttpURLConnection is doing it using url-encoded rather than form-data type that i need. Thanks for your input. Will work on it!